# Using `printf` to output chars given some ASCII numbers

Tags: bash, printf

I've been trying to make `printf` output some chars, given their ASCII numbers (in hex)... something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

hexchars () { printf '\x%s' $@ ;}

hexchars 48 65 6c 6c 6f

Expected output:
Hello
```

For some reason that doesn't work though.  Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer provided by Isaac (accepted answer), I ended up with this function:

```
chr  () { local var ; printf -v var '\\x%x' $@ ; printf "$var" ;}
```

Note, I rewrote his answer a bit in order to improve speed by avoiding the subshell.

```
Result:

~# chr 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c 0x6f
Hello
~# chr 72 101 108 108 111
Hello
~# chr {32..126}
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}
```

I guess the inverse of the `chr` function would be a function like...

```
asc () { printf '%d\n' "'$1"  ;}
asc A
65
chr 65
A
```

Or, if we want strictly hex variants...

```
chrx () { local var ; printf -v var '\\x%s' $@ ; printf "$var\n" ;}
ascx () { printf '%x\n' "'$1"  ;}

chrx 48 65 6c 6c 6f
Hello
ascx A
41
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: What do you mean by "what do you mean"?

Comment: It means: Did it output nothing, output something you can't understand, crash, or turn into a bowl of petunias? I don't usually take my Volvo in for a service and tell the mechanic "It doesn't work". I try to tell him the symptoms, so he does not charge me for balancing the wheels because I couldn't retune the radio.

Comment: You should use `"$@"` not the unqouted one. That is wrong.

Comment: Since you are getting into more details, you need to read : https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/071

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, sure, just that it has to be done in two steps. Like a two step tango:

```
$ printf "$(printf  '\\x%s' 48 65 6c 6c 6f)"; echo
Hello
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$ test () { printf "$(printf  '\\x%s' "$@")"; echo; }
$ test 48 65 6c 6c 6f
Hello
```

Or, to avoid printing on "no arguments":

```
$ test () { [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && printf "$(printf  '\\x%s' "$@")"; echo; }
$ test 48 65 6c 6c 6f
Hello
$
```

That is assuming that the arguments are decimal values between 1 and 127 (empty arguments would be counted but will fail on printing).

Comment: Thank you Isaac!  Accepted answer.

Comment: Sure, YW. @patilan

Comment: None of your proposals works as claimed if you are using a standard compliant printf.

Answer (score 2):

`\x` needs to be followed by a *literal* hexadecimal value:

```
$ printf '\x48\n'
H
$ c=48
$ printf '\x%s\n' "$c"
bash: printf: missing hex digit for \x
\x48
```

Presumably this is because `printf` will expand any hexadecimal literals in the format string as a separate step before using the resulting string as the format.

What you can do instead:

```bsh
unhexlify() {
    for character
    do
        format="\x${character}"
        printf "$format"
    done
    printf '\n'
}
```

Test:

```
$ unhexlify 48 65 6c 6c 6f
Hello
```

Comment: +1. Although, I was so hoping that the OP's one-liner could be somehow made to work.

Comment: This does not work, since `printf` does not expand hex excapes. The printf built into bash however may do...

Comment: @schily It does work with the `printf` built into Bash, which I assume the question was about.

Comment: People who read this may not understand this. This is why I in my answers always mention it when a specific feature is non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

Using **perl** and it's `pack` function we pack two hex digits and print the ASCII representation.

```
charx() {
  perl -le 'print pack "(H2)*", @ARGV' -- "$@"
}
```

---

We use the desk calculator **dc** to input base 16 and print out in their ASCII characters using the **a** command.

```
charx() {
dc <<eof
16i
$(echo "$@" | tr a-f A-F)
[SAz0<a]sa
[LAanln1-dsn0<b]sb
[zsnlaxlbxAan]sc
z0<c
eof
}
```

---

Used as:

```
charx  48 65 6c 6c 6f
```

**Result**

```
 Hello
```